# Compare requirement list with received list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I receive a matrix of requirements that validate corresponding Values as below:

[image: Requirements]

And a current matrix with the completed requirements marked with x:

[image: List to validate]

Is it possible to compare the matrices and return the missing requirements for each Value?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what does your expected output look like?

Comment: How should the result return?

Answer (score 0):

The simplistic answer / option:

Assuming your tables are in A1 in both worksheets and have the same positioning of "Req" and "Value" rows and columns.

Mark the area for the entire table, then create a `Formula` for "conditional format":
`=NOT(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1)`
and select a formatting that corresponds to a mismatch.